# plotting two different graphs in the same placeholder using jquery flot

Tags: jquery, graph, flot

I am using flot to plot the scheduled bill payments of a particular month. How can I differentiate the color of the line-graph plotted with respect to the current day, i.e the past dates should have one color and the future dates should have a different color?

I am using the following code:

```
$.plot($("#placeholder1"),  [current_d1,current_d2],options_current);
```

`current_d1` and `current_d2` are my two arrays and `options_current` is the options defined for the placeholder.

```
var options_current= {

    series: {
      //dashes: { show: true,   shadowSize: 0, steps:true},
    lines: { show: true,lineWidth:5,steps:true},
        points: { show: true,radius:4 },
        color: ('#0000ff'),
        threshold: {below:0, color: "#DF0101"}  
      },
     xaxis:  {min:1,max :max_value_current, tickFormatter: dayFormatter,tickColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)", tickDecimals:0,ticks:max_value} ,
     yaxis:  {min:1,tickFormatter: dollarFormatter} ,

      grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true, 

             borderWidth: 0,

              markings: [ 
                  {xaxis: {from:temp_day, to: temp_day}, color: '#A4A4A4'},
                  {xaxis: {from:1, to: 1}, color: '#000000'},
                  {yaxis: {from:1, to: 1}, color: '#000000'}                      

                           ]

            },

              legend: { position: 'se'}

  };
```

Answer (score 2):

You're providing a global 'color' option for all your lines, which forces them all to the same color (blue).  You just need to omit that option, and Flot will pick different colors for each series.

If you really want to force specific colors, then take a look at the docs; at the top, under [Data Format](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format), note that a series can be either raw data or an object with properties.  If you use the latter form, which is explained a few paragraphs further down, then you can provide different line options, and therefore different colors, for each series.